# How to install dependencies of a program

Tags: apt, package-management, dependencies, shared-library, architecture

I am trying install a program named Teletalk 3G in my ubuntu 15.10. However there seems to be some dependencies missing, so i ran the "ldd" command to see which dependencies were missing. I got these files as "not found":-

```
libfreetype.so.6 => not found
libSM.so.6 => not found
libICE.so.6 => not found
libXrender.so.1 => not found
libfontconfig.so.1 => not found
libXext.so.6 => not found
libX11.so.6 => not found
```

However, i later found out that each of this files are present in
    "/usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu"
So i tried to create symbolic links of these files in "/usr/lib". However this gives an error like "error while loading shared libraries: libfreetype.so.6: wrong ELF class: ELFCLASS64". I googled about this and learned that wrong architecture of libraries is probably the reason.

I would like to know which libraries i need to install to get rid of this problem.

Thank you.

Comment: What's the output of `file <executable>`, just to be sure?

Comment: output of "file Teletalk_3G" :  Teletalk_3G: setuid ELF 32-bit LSB executable, Intel 80386, version 1 (SYSV), dynamically linked, interpreter /lib/ld-linux.so.2, for GNU/Linux 2.6.15, BuildID[sha1]=cd0be0d9a95ef23dbdce3247fac5807f6735d4d2, not stripped

Answer (score 1, accepted):

First, remove the symlinks from `/usr/lib`, as those wil trick the linker;

Then, install the 32-bit version of the libraries:

```
sudo apt-get install libfreetype6:i386 libsm6:i386 libice6:i386 libxrender1:i386 libfontconfig1:i386 libxext6:i386 libx11-6:i386
```

The linker should be able to find them automatically without extra configuration afterwards.

Comment: say, if i face this kind of problem again, how can i find the name of the libraries that need to be installed ??  Thank You.

Comment: @KAI10 You're welcome. I found them using `apt-file` (`apt-file search '<filename>'`) because I'm more used to it but since `apt-file` searches all sources listed in `/etc/apt/sources.list` sometimes it may be handier to search http://packages.ubuntu.com, which will report only results in the default repositories.

Comment: if you do this, you can't remove them with autoremove, can you?